# Ingres connection on an IIS deployed site

Tags: iis, ibatis, ingres

I have a .net 2.0 app being hosted on IIS, that connects to a Ingres DB. The connection uses iBatis with an ODBC driver to connect to an ingres database being protected behind an installation password.

For some reason, when I'm debugging my code, everything runs fine. It establishes the connection without any problems. However, when I try to host the site on my local IIS, ingres comes back with this error

```
ERROR [5000H] [CA][Ingres ODBC Driver][Ingres]User authorization check failed.
        Your user identifier was not known to this installation.
        Contact your system manager for further assistance.
ERROR [08S01] [CA][Ingres ODBC Driver][Ingres]The connection to the server has been aborted.
```

I'm wondering why the installation password would work fine against my debug session, and refuse to connect behind IIS? Does IIS use a different 'name' that isn't my computer name to establish a connection with the installation password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is being rejected because the target server is not aware of the user trying to connect or that user has not been added. Check to see if the process owner of your local IIS instance is a valid ingres user. IIRC the account name is normally something like IUSR_MACHINENAME, where MACHINENAME is the hostname of your IIS box. Add the user account using the following SQL on the server:

```
echo "create user IUSR_MACHINENAME\g" | sql iidbdb
```